# Nginx doesn't see or use subdomain config

Tags: nginx, proxy, subdomain, django

**Problem:** nginx doesn't apply configuration for subdomain if there are domain and subdomain config at the same time.

**Disclaimer:** I'm new to nginx and server deployment.

**Question:**
What I do wrong with nginx configuration?

**Additional info:**

- Nginx 1.18.0
- Ubuntu 20.04

**Details:**
I have main domain (it's my portfolio) (let's say example.com) and subdomain (todo-tracker.example.com). Both are django projects started with gunicorn (main on 127.0.0.1:8000, todo-tracker on 127.0.0.1:8001).

I have two sites-available config files:

- default - for main domain

```
    server {
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /static {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/portfolio/portfolio/staticfiles;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }

    server {
        if ($host = example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
        server_name example.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

- todo-tracker - for subdomain

```
    server {
        server_name todo-tracker.example.com;

        location / {
               proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

Both files passes nginx -t test.
Both files are added to sites-enabled with symbolic links and both are valid.

I've conducted some experiments:

1. If I remove todo-tracker config file and put configuration in default config like this, it redirects just fine and opens my todo-tracker, however in this case I don't have access to portfolio.

```
    server {
        server_name todo-tracker.example.com;
    
        location / {
               proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    ... ssl config ...
```

2. I've removed default config and kept only todo-tracker one. In this case it didn't work at all, so I made the conclusion that todo-tracker's config doesn't load properly.
3. I've also tried to combine two files (i.e. just copy subdomain config into default config file). In this case main domain loaded successfully and subdomain was proxied to main domain so that it returned the django error "add to allowed hosts".

**nginx -T**

```
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

    events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        ## Block spammers and other unwanted visitors  ##   
        include /etc/nginx/blockips.conf;
    }


    #mail {
    #   # See sample authentication script at:
    #   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
    # 
    #   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    #   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    #   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
    # 
    #   server {
    #       listen     localhost:110;
    #       protocol   pop3;
    #       proxy      on;
    #   }
    # 
    #   server {
    #       listen     localhost:143;
    #       protocol   imap;
    #       proxy      on;
    #   }
    #}

    # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
    load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

    # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
    load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

    # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
    load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

    # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
    load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

    # configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

    types {
        text/html                             html htm shtml;
        text/css                              css;
        text/xml                              xml;
        image/gif                             gif;
        image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
        application/javascript                js;
        application/atom+xml                  atom;
        application/rss+xml                   rss;

        text/mathml                           mml;
        text/plain                            txt;
        text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
        text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
        text/x-component                      htc;

        image/png                             png;
        image/tiff                            tif tiff;
        image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
        image/x-icon                          ico;
        image/x-jng                           jng;
        image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
        image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
        image/webp                            webp;

        application/font-woff                 woff;
        application/java-archive              jar war ear;
        application/json                      json;
        application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
        application/msword                    doc;
        application/pdf                       pdf;
        application/postscript                ps eps ai;
        application/rtf                       rtf;
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
        application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
        application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
        application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
        application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
        application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
        application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
        application/x-cocoa                   cco;
        application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
        application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
        application/x-makeself                run;
        application/x-perl                    pl pm;
        application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
        application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
        application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
        application/x-sea                     sea;
        application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
        application/x-stuffit                 sit;
        application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
        application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
        application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
        application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
        application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
        application/zip                       zip;

        application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
        application/octet-stream              deb;
        application/octet-stream              dmg;
        application/octet-stream              iso img;
        application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

        audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
        audio/mpeg                            mp3;
        audio/ogg                             ogg;
        audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
        audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

        video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
        video/mp2t                            ts;
        video/mp4                             mp4;
        video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
        video/quicktime                       mov;
        video/webm                            webm;
        video/x-flv                           flv;
        video/x-m4v                           m4v;
        video/x-mng                           mng;
        video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
        video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
        video/x-msvideo                       avi;
    }

    # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
    server {
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
        }

        location /static {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/portfolio/portfolio/staticfiles;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }

    server {
        if ($host = example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
        server_name example.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }

    # configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
    # This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
    # manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
    # updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
    # the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
    # this file.

    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA";

    # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/todo-tracker:
    server {
        server_name todo-tracker.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
        }

        #location /static {
        #    autoindex on;
        #    alias /home/portfolio/portfolio/staticfiles;
        #}

    }


    # configuration file /etc/nginx/blockips.conf:
    deny 152.89.196.211;
    deny 35.195.241.126;
```

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` (note capital case) to show the complete nginx configuration.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Add it at the bottom of the question. Hope I did it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration for `todo-tracker` is missing the `listen` directive(s).

Comment: thanks. I created a new ssl certificate for my subdomain and it worked!